# Concrete Grid system - Am I misunderstanding the purpose?

Tags: html, css

This is a CSS framework I am looking at:

http://davidlumley.github.io/concrete/

This is the CSS: https://github.com/davidlumley/concrete

Am I misunderstanding what is going on here, because the demo page seems like it should be showing me columns, but in all the examples I see there is just a single row (one column). I don't know if it isn't working in my browser, or I have mis-understood the point of Concrete?

Comment: I don't follow. "but in all the examples..." which examples?

Comment: How wide is your browser window?  Once you go below a certain width, all the columns stack up vertically.  I see multiple columns, side by side.

Comment: It seems that in Firefox (for me) all columns are at 100% width, in Chrome everything seems fine.

Comment: It's not so much Concrete, but more like mud. It doesn't seem to work in FF.

Comment: I tried this on a 1920 x 1080 monitor in the latest Chrome and Firefox. Chrome works, but the Fox shows each div full width and each on its own line. Doesn't work in IE either.

Comment: Concrete.css is blank in FF. I guess the [raw path](https://raw.github.com/davidlumley/concrete/master/concrete.css) is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS on the demo page is not loading up, that's why there is no effect on the page. Just copy the css from this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidlumley/concrete/master/concrete.css) and use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your screen really small? Its responsive so collapses down to one col on smaller devices.

Comment: I'm on a laptop >1000px wide